# OSx time/locale of a struct tm

Tags: c, macos, time, timezone

I'm trying to create a struct tm with a local timezone on OSx.

```
#import <time.h>
#import <xlocale.h>//This is here because I was trying strptime_l

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  struct tm start;
  memset(&start, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
  const char *formatString = "%m/%d/%Y %R";

  (void) strptime("7/15/2013 16:00", formatString, &start);//Mon Jul 15 @ 4pm EST

  printf("%s\n", start.tm_zone); //prints null

  if (!start.tm_zone) {
     time_t now;
     time(&now);
     printf("%s\n", localtime(&now)->tm_zone);//But I have the right timezone here.
  }

  return 0;
}
```

According to the [OSx docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/strptime_l.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/strptime_l):

> While the strptime() function uses the current locale, the strptime_l()
>   function may be passed a locale directly. See xlocale(3) for more information.

My end goal is to be able to create an NSDate object so I can eventually create a calendar event on the iPhone.

Comment: Why don't you use NSDateFormatter to create an NSDate object?

Comment: @MartinR I could. But I'd still like to understand what's wrong with this sample.

Comment: "If the format string does not contain enough conversion specifications to completely specify the resulting struct tm, the unspecified members of tm are left untouched."  Maybe it does not know if your are in EST or EDT.  Could use `const char *formatString = "%m/%d/%Y %R %Z"; strptime("7/15/2013 16:00 EST"`.  Note: I suspect your example time is "Mon Jul 15 @ 4pm EDT", not EST.